# android in drag'n'drop ,img can be drag ,but not drop

Tags: android

I'm doing lots of stuff but i can't get.The problem which i face is when i drag the image its work ok and when i drop it it can't replace or can't see,
below i have put my code please help where i am wrong.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
TextView comments;
ImageView img, buttonTarget;

String commentMsg;

MyDragEventListener myDragEventListener = new MyDragEventListener();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImg);

    buttonTarget = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonTarget);

    // Create and set the tags for the Buttons
    final String IMG_TAG = "img";

    img.setTag(IMG_TAG);

    img.setOnLongClickListener(sourceimgLongClickListener);

    img.setOnDragListener(myDragEventListener);
    buttonTarget.setOnDragListener(myDragEventListener);
}

ImageView.OnLongClickListener sourceimgLongClickListener = new ImageView.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v.getTag());

        String[] clipDescription = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN };
        ClipData dragData = new ClipData((CharSequence) v.getTag(),
                clipDescription, item);
        DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new MyDragShadowBuilder(v);

        v.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, v, 0);

        return true;
    }
};

private static class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
    // private static Drawable shadow;

    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v) {
        super(v);
        // shadow = new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point size, Point touch) {
        int width = getView().getWidth();
        int height = getView().getHeight();
        // Log.i("metrix",""+width+"  "+height);
        // shadow.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        size.set(width, height);
        touch.set(width / 2, height / 2);
        // Log.i("metrix",""+width/5+"  "+height/5);
    }

    /*
     * @Override public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
     * shadow.draw(canvas); }
     */

}

protected class MyDragEventListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            Log.i("action", "start");
            // All involved view accept ACTION_DRAG_STARTED for
            // MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN

            if (event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(
                    ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                return true; // Accept
            } else {
                return false; // reject
            }

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            Log.i("action", "entered");

            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            Log.i("action", "location");

            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            Log.i("action", "exited");

            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Log.i("action", "drop");
            // Gets the item containing the dragged data
            // ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);

            // If apply only if drop on buttonTarget
            if (v == buttonTarget) {

                // Retrieve the source view using getLocalState()
                View dragView = (View) event.getLocalState();

                ((ImageView) v)
                        .setBackgroundDrawable(((ImageView) dragView)
                                .getBackground());
            }

            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            Log.i("action", "ended");
            if (event.getResult()) {
            } else {
            }

            return true;
        default: // unknown case
            return false;

        }
    }
}
```

}

so the above is my code please check it and suggestion me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your grammar is somewhat confusing, excuse me for saying that. And use image instead of img is more readable. Describe your problem in a direct way and don't tell a story.
"It can't replace(what) or can't see(what)".
Actually, what is your initial state of view or what views is that got displayed after the first time app running?
What behaviour that do you expect or what do you want to SEE after you drop "it" to another "view"?